# Make Marker Non Draggable from Map Option

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

In my application two markers have been shown and in between these maker a route has been formed.

My task is to prevent marker to drag from the map option; because I have not taken any reference or variable with respect to the marker.

I have tried with the following code .

```
        var mapOptions = 
                {
                 zoom: 7,
                 center: mumbai,
                 draggable: false

        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);
```

And,

```
        map.setOptions({draggable: false});
```

Both the way are not working for me.

Comment: Not possible without access to the marker object.

Answer (score 0):

The `draggable` should be inside the marker options and not inside the map options. What you're doing will surely not work. `draggable` should be like this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    draggable:false,
    title:"You can't drag me!"
});
```

Also, markers are supposed to be not draggable if the `draggable` option is not set at all like this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title:"You can't drag me!"
});
```

So if you are not adding this to your marker, it should not be draggable, just as what's needed for your use case.

Hope this helps!